# Firebase: cloud firestore rules: permission denied

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My collection `/users/` has the following access rule defined:

```
  allow read: if isCurrentUser(userId) || isDoctor() || isAdmin();
  allow write: if (isCurrentUser(userId) && !isModifyingPermissions() );

  function isModifyingPermissions(){
    return request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["permissions"]);
  }
```

A document within the `users` collection has a series of properties:

- name
- email
- permissions
- ...

Test:

- perform a non-destructive update of the connected user's matching document
- `myDocument.update({name: 'Hello Stackoverflow'});`

Observed behavior:

- If the existing resource has the "permissions" property, then the update is denied
- If the existing resource doesn't have the "permissions" property, then the update is allowed

Expected behavior:
 - if the requested update contains the "permissions" property, then the update is denied
 - hatever the existing object contains, allow the update as long as it doesn't contain the "permissions" property.

I'm using Angular5 (Ionic3) with Angularfire.

Is my expectation wrong?